# Automatically write to field in django model based on lookup in another model

Tags: python, django

Using Django 1.8 and Python 3.4.0, I'm looking for a way to automatically save a foreign key-reference in my model, based on the value in another field. The models basically resemble the following tables:

**Main model**

```
NAME                fkCATEGORY
Joshua the Pig      1
Anders the Cow      2
Piglet              1
Cowabunga           2
Fishy Goldtail      3
```

**Category model**

```
CATEGORY_ID         CATEGORY
1                   Pig
2                   Cow
3                   Fish
```

**Resulting table**

```
NAME                CATEGORY
Joshua the Pig      Pig
Anders the Cow      Cow
Piglet              Pig
Cowabunga           Cow
Fishy Goldtail      Fish
```

This is simple to realize in django. However, in "main model" the fkCATEGORY is null and I want it to be automatically be populate based on same search words in another model:

**Keyword model**

```
KEYWORD             fkCATEGORY
pig                 1
cow                 2
fish                3
```

Probably I'll make the keyword a regex but for now it doesn't matter.

Preferably I want to populate the "main model" fkCATEGORY field in two ways:
1. Bulky, running through all rows and updating the field as I have updated the Category and Keyword models. I think I'll write a command for this and access it through manage.py;
2. On saving a new row in Main model, using signal I think.

...yet I'm all stuck. I don't think this ought to be that struggling but I can't manage to find a good solution.

Anyone care to give me a push in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override main model's save method like this:

```
#suppose category model looks like this
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)

#main model
class MainModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, default=None)


    def save(self):
        for c in Category.objects.all():
            if c.category in self.name:
               self.category = c
               break
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you ruddra. Based on your answer I managed to solve the problem.